# Download ZIP file From path stored in Database MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Need to download zip file content, path is stored in sqlserver, i am using FILERESULT Action method in controller.
My Controller looks like this:

```
public FileResult Download(string id)
{
    string txtvalue = null; int cat = 0;

    string searchType = Session["type"].ToString();
    if (searchType == "name")
    {
        txtvalue = Session["item"].ToString();
    }
    else if (searchType == "cat")
    {
        cat = Convert.ToInt32(Session["item"]);
    }
    int fid =Convert.ToInt32(Session["Fid"]);
    var files = _urepo.GetprojectName(fid);
    string filename = (from f in files
                       select f.PRJ_LOCATION).SingleOrDefault();
    string contentType = "application/zip";

    return File(filename, contentType,"download"+filename);
}
```

**But only file  is downloading...contents are not downloading..
any help will be apprciated**

Comment: Are you sure the file exists?

Comment: What does _"file is downloading...contents are not downloading"_ mean exactly?

Comment: Check that the returned file actually exists on the server. Something like this before your return statement: `if(!System.IO.File.Exists(filename)) throw new FileNotFoundException();`

Comment: @Lloyd File Exists.
even It is Downloading.But It Doesn't contains Contents inside.

Comment: @CodeCaster Files Are Downloading perfectly with zip Format,but when i open them contents are missing which are supposed to be there archived in file

Comment: Yeah, we can't answer that. It means that `files` does not contain what you expect it to.

Comment: How can we Ask for save location each time when user clicks Download button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this,first of all you need to check whether you are fetching file from Database or not? so condition will help you,another thing try to change **"Content Type"**

```
if (filename != null)
 {
      contentType = "application/force-download";
      return File(filename, contentType, Path.GetFileName(filename));
 }
```

Note : I have not posted full code,but the only place where chances mistake.

Comment: Actually,Content By default is **Zip**.
File is downloading in Zip Format.
But When I open File.It Does not Contain Anything.

Answer (score 1):

**I Got It**,
Actually As CodeCaster Said, **Contents were Missing While Archiving**.
Later I appended data With Ajax Call.

```
public FileResult Download()
        {
            int Id = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["FileID"]);

            var files = _urepo.GetprojectName(Id);
            string filename = (from f in files
                               select f.PRJ_LOCATION).SingleOrDefault();
            string contentType = "application/zip";
           byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename);

            string file=filename.Substring(filename.LastIndexOf("\\")+1);
             return File(fileBytes, contentType, file);
        }
```

Thank You All.